# Class Extends wont work in include_once()

Tags: php, class

My file structure is like this:

```
> main.php
   - file1.php
   - file2.php
   - file3.php
```

I have a class inside `file1.php`:

```
class ClassFileOne extends OtherClassInSameFile
{

}
```

that I would like to be used inside `file2.php`:

```
class ClassFileTwo extends ClassFileOne
{

}
```

However when I do this I get **Error:** `Fatal error: Class 'ClassFileOne' not found in`.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: In `file2.php` you need `include('file1.php');` or `require` etc... Or use an autoloader http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: You need to either manually include the required files or, better, setup an auto loading strategy.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because your file cannot read the other class files.

Let's say this is the file structure:

```
- root
    - main.php
    - ClassA.php
    - ClassB.php
    - ClassC.php
```

And let's say I want `ClassC` to extend `ClassB` and `ClassB` to extend `ClassA`.

---

## 1. Manual load

#### main.php

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/ClassC.php';
new ClassC();
```

#### ClassA.php

```
<?php

class ClassA{

    public function __construct(){
        echo 'Hello World.';
    }

}
```

#### ClassB.php

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/ClassA.php';

class ClassB extends ClassA{

}
```

#### ClassC.php

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/ClassB.php';

class ClassC extends ClassB{

}
```

Notice the `require` in the `ClassB` and `ClassC`. And the result of `main.php` would be:

```
Hello World.
```

---

## 2. Autoload (without namespace)

You can create your own [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) by creating a file (example `autoload.php`) and include it in your main. So the file structure will become:

```
- root
    - autoload.php
    - main.php
    - ClassA.php
    - ClassB.php
    - ClassC.php
```

#### main.php

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';
new ClassC();
```

#### ClassA.php

```
<?php

class ClassA{

    public function __construct(){

        echo 'Hello World';

    }

}
```

**Note**: The `ClassA` is the same as the other example.

#### ClassB.php

```
<?php

class ClassB extends ClassA{

}
```

#### ClassC.php

```
<?php

class ClassC extends ClassB{

}
```

**Note**: The `ClassB` and `ClassC` no longer has the `require` at the top of the file.

#### autoload.php

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function($class){

    $path = __DIR__ . '/' . $class . '.php';

    if(file_exists($path))
        require $path;

});
```

#### Breakdown of autoload.php

You start by registering your custom autoloader which will take a callable as parameter:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){

});
```

At this point, if you `var_dump($class)` inside the autoloader, you'll get:

```
ClassC
```

So with the name of the class, you want to locate the file to load:

```
$path = __DIR__ . '/' . $class . '.php';
```

And before loading the file, you want to make sure that the file exists.

```
if(file_exists($path))
    require $path;
```

If the file doesn't exist, it will simply go to the next autoloader.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I only have to call `new ClassC` inside `main.php`? I'm liking the autoload method but I'm not sure I get it.

Comment: @Borsn No, you can call whatever class you want with the autoload method. I'm just showing an example that the `extends` is working in the `ClassC`.

Comment: @Borsn What do you not get with the `autoload` method?

Comment: Well how do I call this function for example `spl_autoload_register(function($class){}` I need to know the file name and after I `include_once(autoloader.php)` inside `main.php` then I call them individually?

Comment: @Borsn No, you only have to include the `autoloader`. Once you try to initialize a class, it will call the function inside the `spl_autoload_register` automatically with the class that it's trying to initialize. So after you include it, you can initialize `ClassA`, `ClassB` or `ClassC`.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of file2.php, you need `require_once('path/to/file1.php')`

Using require instead of include will cause an error if file1 is not found, so you can easily see if your path is incorrect.